# How to show the slide dots using the Slick Carousel module?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [Slick Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) module and I can't see where / how to add the paging dots below the carousel images. The module boasts that it has this feature.

I've tried altering the .js file (and the .min version) but can't seem to force them to show.

Does anyone know where to turn this on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the slick module **and** the slick ui module, after that go to Configuration -> Media -> Slick Carousel (admin/config/media/slick).

From there you can edit the default profile for slick carousel or create a custom one. There you can enable or disable dots and of course various other options.

[image: Slick settings]